# How to copy this class from Chrome Elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

i'm editing some css from a website and using Chrome's Inspector.

How can i copy the section#home.l ... as seen in the picture?
[image]

Because if i try right click or something, nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click (Mac Control + Click) the element -> Copy -> Copy Selector

[image: Copy Selector]

For the `element#id.class.class.class` path select the properties tab and you can copy it by selecting it. **THIS IS NOT THE RECOMMENDED WAY TO CREATE CSS RULES**
[image: full path]

Comment: If i copy the selector, it only comes a #home. I trying to get the section#home.l-... full, as seen in the image. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me why it isnt recommended?